# Failed attempt at web sraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

After a failed attempt using just BeautifulSoup, I decided to try this with Selenium. The script is an attempt to get the subtitles for the specific TV Show or movie that is defined. If you look at the code, you'll see that there are quite a few `wait.until` with what seems enough of a pause to let Selenium do its work. I'm still getting the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000104652fa8 chromedriver + 4886440
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001045d0643 chromedriver + 4351555
....
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
# Import the necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)


# Create a webdriver instanceand go to the website
browser.get('https://english-subtitles.org/')

# Wait for the page to fully load before trying to interact with it
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 35)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))


# Enter the name of the show in the search bar
search_input = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 25)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q')))
search_input.send_keys("Babylon Berlin")


# Click the search button
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, e0)
search_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')))
search_button.click()


# Parse the HTML content of the search results page
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find the download link of all episodes
episodes = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"download/\d+"))

for item in episodes:
    # get url of item
    link = item["href"]
    # normalize episode name
    name = item.text.lower().replace(" ", "_")

    print(f"Downloading {name} from {link} url ...")

    # Download the subtitle file
    subtitle_file = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
        
    # Save the file
    with open(f"{name}.srt", 'wb') as file:
        file.write(subtitle_file.content)

# Close the webdriver instance
browser.quit()
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? Is it impossible to scrape this kind of site? I need the subtitles to analyze them and it is very tedious to have to download them manually. Can anybody tell me the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

JM

EDIT: Here's a modified version of the script @Jurakin provided. This is an attempt to do a batch download of all the subtitles I'm interested in. It doesn't work completely. It gets interrupted after the second download is completed no matter what the amount of files you tell it to download.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os.path
import re

session = requests.Session()

query = input("Enter your search: ")

page = session.post("https://english-subtitles.org/index.php?do=search", data={"do": "search", "subaction": "search", "story": query})
page.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("div", class_="tbl")
if results:
    for index, result in enumerate(results):
        title = result.find("h2").text
        subtitle = result.find("h3").text
        info = result.find("h4").text
        mark = result.find("div", class_="mark").text
        
        print(f"{index}: {title}")
        print(f" - {subtitle}")
        print(f" - {info}")
        print(f" - {mark}")
else:
    raise RuntimeError("no result")

# Parse the user input string to a list of numbers
input_num_list = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', input("Select result: "))]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory": os.path.abspath("."), "download.prompt_for_download": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Iterate over the numbers in the list and download the corresponding subtitles
for query in input_num_list:
    if query < 0 or query >= len(results):
        raise ValueError("invalid select")

    link = results[query].find("a", href=True)
    assert link, "link not found"

    # Create a webdriver instanceand go to the website
    driver.get(link["href"])

    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="content"]/section/div[2]/div[2]/form/input[@type="submit"]""")
    assert element, "no download button found"
    element.click()

    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="content"]/section/div[2]/div/form/input[@type="submit"]""")
    assert element, "no download button2 found"
    element.click()

    # wait until file downloads
    time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Any idea which line the error originates from? If the stack trace doesn't point to a line, try debugging it step by step.

Comment: Check this line `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, e0)` it should be `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)`

Comment: Thanks MB and Azky. I noticed that I had introduced a typo in (browser, e0). That was part of the problem. With the alternative scripts Jurakin and AbiSaran provided, all those problems went away.

Comment: @jfontana Use `map(int, input("Select result: ").split(","))` instead of `[int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', input("Select result: "))]`, you don't need a regex for that. When you give input to `select result`, the `split` function splits the string with a comma and then `map` converts it to integers, so give the input as `2,3,5,11`.

Comment: Thanks @Jurakin! I just had to add an explicit wait but it worked perfectly. Playing with this, I discovered that 'https://english-subtitles.org' redirects you to 'https://www.podnapisi.net' where if you do a search for a TV-show all of the episodes for all of the sessions appear in the same page. The code I used for english-subtitles.org obviously doesn't work and it has to be adapted but it looks very promissing because it would simplify things and allow one to download the subtitles for entire series in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created selenium-beautifulsoup program to search and download subtitles into current folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os.path

session = requests.Session()

query = input("Enter your search: ")

page = session.post("https://english-subtitles.org/index.php?do=search", data={"do": "search", "subaction": "search", "story": query})
page.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("div", class_="tbl")
if results:
    for index, result in enumerate(results):
        title = result.find("h2").text
        subtitle = result.find("h3").text
        info = result.find("h4").text
        mark = result.find("div", class_="mark").text
        
        print(f"{index}: {title}")
        print(f" - {subtitle}")
        print(f" - {info}")
        print(f" - {mark}")
else:
    raise RuntimeError("no result")

query = int(input("Select result: "))

if query < 0 or query >= len(results):
    raise ValueError("invalid select")

link = results[query].find("a", href=True)
assert link, "link not found"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory": os.path.abspath("."), "download.prompt_for_download": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Create a webdriver instanceand go to the website
driver.get(link["href"])

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="content"]/section/div[2]/div[2]/form/input[@type="submit"]""")
assert element, "no download button found"
element.click()

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, """//*[@id="content"]/section/div[2]/div/form/input[@type="submit"]""")
assert element, "no download button2 found"
element.click()

# wait until file downloads
time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks again @Jurakin! Your script worked brilliantly. Going through it I realized how many things were missing  and I learned a lot. I edited my OP with a revised version that attemps to batch download all or a subset of the subtitles by introducing e.g. 0-11, 3-8, at the prompt 'Select result:'. It manages to download two of the targeted subtitle files and then it stops. It is a start, though. One question, all the lists your script outputs are exactly 11 possible downloads. Is this number limit intended for some reason?

Comment: OK, I see. It shows from 0 to 11 (actually 12 links, not 11) because that's the number of results shown in the first page of results after the search. If you want to continue with more, you have to click on the button 'Next page >' that appears on the lower right part of the screen. This is getting me much closer to my goal. I just need to figure out how to tell Selenium to download all the links in the first page produced by the search and continue to the following pages until all of the subtitles for all the episodes are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

options = Options()

prefs = {"download.default_directory": "..\\Downloads\\",
         "download.prompt_for_download": False,
         "download.directory_upgrade": True,
         "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
         "profile.default_content_settings_values.automatic_downloads": 1,
         "plugins.plugins_disabled": False,
         "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
         "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
         }
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

webdriver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get("https://english-subtitles.org/")
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.ID, "story").send_keys("Babylon Berlin")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ser-but").click()
links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sub a[href]")

urls = []
for link in links:
    urls.append(link.get_attribute("href"))

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".downloadlink").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".downloadlink").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks @AbiSaran! Your script kind of does what I was attempting when modifying Jurakin's. His script is very useful because many times I want to see what's there before I decide. In most cases, though, what I want is to download all of the English subtitles there are for a particular show. Yours seems to attempt a batch download. However, I'm getting multiple copies of the same subt, like this: 83554-the-americans-s06e09-[English-subtitles.org].zip, 83555-the-americans-s06e09-[English-subtitles.org].zip ...

Comment: Now I see that this was not a problem with your script but rather an artifact of what the search produces in that particular site. Your script correctly downloads all of the links the search yields. The problem with these sites is that many times they give you a short list and then they give you a button to see the next few hits and so on. Logical if they get their revenue from adds. I wonder if there is a way to keep on going until you've downloaded all of the available subtitles. There must be.